# Как вывести ссылку, если не найдено значение в массиве?

Tags: php

Сейчас сделано так, что если находит значение в массиве, то выводится ссылка.
А как сделать, чтобы она выводилась, если значение не найдено?

```
<?php if (in_array('find-us', $pages)) { ?><a href="?p=find-us"><img src="images/icon_map.jpg" /></a><?php } ?>
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Поставьте оператор отрицания (`!`) перед `in_array`:

```
if (!in_array('find-us', $pages)) {
```

http://php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.logical.php